# Why does my Laravel 6 and Angular website show 'Not Found: The requested URL was not found on this server' error after deploying online?

Tags: angular, laravel

I have deployed my `website` built with `Laravel 6` and `Angular` at https://www.aswaktinghir.com/. It displays correctly, and I have a menu that displays different `components` properly. However, my issue arises when I click on, for example, '`Blog Tinghir`.' It displays the '`Blog Tinghir`' `component`, but if I `refresh` the page, it gives me the error: '`Not Found: The requested URL was not found on this server`.'

How can I resolve this problem?"

**menu.component.html**

```
<ul class="navigation"> 
            <li>
                <a routerLink="/">Acceuil</a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a routerLink="/tinghirs">Blog Tinghir</a> 
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a routerLink="annonces/chat">Chat</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink="/annonces">cherche Annonces</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink="annonces/profil">Profil</a>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a routerLink="annonces/chat2">chat2</a> 
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a routerLink="annonces/cart">Cart</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="!currentUser">
                <a routerLink="/login">Connexion</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="!currentUser">
                <a routerLink="/register">Inscription</a>
            </li>
            
            <li *ngIf="currentUser" >
                <button (click)="logOut()" class="btn-logOut">Deconnexion</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```